# Remove .php with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

How can I change this url: http://localhost/index.php/Department/2

to this one: http://localhost/index/Department/2

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^index/(.*) index.php/$1
```

And if you want to strip the `index/` too, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Try to set the `R` flag to enforce an external redirect to see if and where the request is redirected to.

Comment: Oh, I hope you didn’t forget the obligatory `RewriteEngine on` to enable mod_rewrite.

Comment: I have tried;

RewriteRule ^index/(.*) index.php/$1 -R 

but I get an internal server error. RewriteEngine is on.

Comment: Flags are written as comma separated list in brackets. So: `RewriteRule ^index/(.*) index.php/$1 [R]`